# Setting a small image on map on some coordinates using D3.js and GeoJson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I want to compare some coordinates given by user with the coordinates in the geojson file, and if the condition turns out to be true then i want to draw a small circular image on that position defined by the coordinates(really small like a symbol or something). What do I have to write inside the d3.json method to access the coordinates from geojson file, compare it and plot an image on it?
Any help will be appreciated.

This is a small part of my geojson file

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "id":"Andhra Pradesh", "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 80.149167, 13.618300 ], [ 80.142031, 13.544708 ], [ 80.126421, 13.584849 ], [ 80.158087, 13.591093 ], [ 80.120622, 13.605812 ], [ 80.149167, 13.618300 ] ] ], [ [ [ 82.258801, 16.689980 ], [ 82.285562, 16.697563 ], [ 82.368074, 16.723877 ], [ 82.311876, 16.602562 ], [ 82.258801, 16.689980 ] ] ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need another dataset for what you want. These coordinates you have in your `geometry` collection are used to draw the path. See the documentation:

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-objects

In other words, those are just the coordinates to the "lines" (borders) you see on the map. I believe you want to compare coordinates for positions *inside* each state (path), like cities or other POI, is that correct?

In that case, you have two options: You can easily draw a circle or whatever according to the coordinates given by the user, or if these coordinates are cities, you can search for another JSON file with geographic data for these cities, and compare user's input with these coordinates.

Once you have these coordinates (let's call them `longitude` and `latitude`), you can plot them like this:

```
svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function() {
        return projection(longitude);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection(latitude);
    })
    .attr("r", whatever)
    .style("fill", whatever);
```

`svg` is the variable that you used to append the SVG, and `projection` the one you used to set the projection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes those coordinates are of cities which i want to compare. Can you tell where I can find the json for indian cities. This is the link I got from a question asked on stackoverflow but cant understand which one to download http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Comment: I don't know where you can find it... But now that you know *what* you need, things are going to be easier! :-)

Comment: Thanks :) and yea how to draw a marker or an image over that place?

Comment: Thanks :-) In case I want to draw marker with just the place name? What changes I have to make in the code?

Comment: Just a circle, but this time i just have the name of the place and not the coordinates

Comment: Now I understand your question... no, it's impossible. You need to have the coordinates, something like this: https://gist.github.com/dastagirkhan/00a6f6e32425e0944241. With a JSON like this, you can get the coordinates according to the name.